# How we can automate real browser instead of using selenium browser instance

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, browser, automation

I am trying to scrape a website, but it is not loading in selenium. When I browse that website in my "real" chrome browser, everything works fine. Is there any way I can use my real browser with python to automate stuff, instead of using selenium??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using selenium we can automate real browsers.

If in case the website is not loading via selenium, you can check if adding desired capabilities helps.
Here we can set proxy, disable extensions etc. There are many options available.
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities

Also if you can share what kind of error is displayed that would be helpful.

Comment: Website is detecting selenium somehow and I am getting access denied. Looks like its some kind of anti-bot technology.

Comment: You can also try Robot Framework browser library. Its not based on selenium.  https://robotframework-browser.org/. Let me know if it helps